# How to make a model rotatable and scalable via gestures (SparkAR, planar image tracking)?

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I have a simple SparkAR app, there is a 3D model, attached to the planar tracker, which tracks an image target. How can I make this 3D model rotatable and scalable via gestures?

---

What I tried:

I tried code from [this tutorial](https://www.sparkar.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/tutorials/interacting-objects-surroundings), it works in case of just planar tracking, but for some reason doesn't work if the tracker has an image target. It allows me to scale a model ones and doesn't work after it.

I also tried  [this solution](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/reference/classes/reactivemodule.rotation/), it allows rotation and scaling, but it makes the model "detached" from the tracked image, so when I move my phone the model also moves around.

---

How can I make a 3D model, (attached to the planar tracker which tracks image target) rotatable and scalable via finger gestures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this one actually is super easy! "Dancing" is my model, it is a child of imageTracker:

[image]

You need to create this graph, and thats it!

[image]

Yellow ones created by clicking on "position" and "rotation" in the inspector panel of you model.